# Best practices for using workflows in Github Actions

Tags: python, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Github Actions provides multiple options to run different commands on the source code. I am wondering about the best practices on when to create multiple workflows, multiple jobs vs multiple steps.

For example, I use GitHub actions for a python project and I want to run a test and lint-check using Github actions. Should I create two separate workflows for this? Or two separate jobs on the same workflow? or even two separate steps in the same job?

How should I decide between those?

Comment: Well, are the tasks independent? For example, should the tests run if the linting fails, or should the CI/CD stop right there?

Comment: jobs allow you to run things in parallel, but splitting things into jobs means you need to checkout the code again and again. I would split it up in logical parts: TEST, DEV DEPLOYMENT, PROD DEPLOYMENT.

Comment: I would recommend the lecture of [this article about CI/CD Best practices](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/ci-cd-guide/ci-cd-best-practices/). There is no right answer, it will most of the time depends on the context you are working with, and your concerns regarding performance, time of execution, metrics, maintenance, and so on... I suggest in your case to test both ideas, and see which one looks the best in your context.

Comment: I would prefer to have independent tasks. But it would be awesome to share logical steps like checkout and building of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the lecture on [this article about CI/CD Best practices](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/ci-cd-guide/ci-cd-best-practices/). There is no right answer, it will most of the time depends on the context you are working with, and your concerns regarding performance, time of execution, metrics, maintenance, and so on... I suggest in your case to test both ideas and see which one looks the best in your context

PS: As this is not answered I take this answer from [@GuiFalourd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8496462/guifalourd) as the answer.